# Wrong result of mysql_field_table()

Tags: php, mysql

I think something wrong with `mysql_field_table`

My query :

```
 SELECT partners.buyer,
        calls_nc_sell_daily.market,
        partners.name,
        calls_nc_sell_daily.partner_id_fk as 'partners_id_fk',
        partners.seller
   FROM partners, calls_nc_sell_daily
  WHERE calls_nc_sell_daily.date >= '$date_start'
    AND calls_nc_sell_daily.date <= '$date_stop'
    AND partners.id = calls_nc_sell_daily.partner_id_fk
```

WHEN result field parsed by following PHP fragment:

```
$tables = array();
for($i=0;$i<$elements;$i++) {
   $name =  mysql_field_name($result,$i);
   $tables[$name] = mysql_field_table($result,$name);
}
print_r($tables);
```

Expected:

```
Array
(
    [buyer] => partners
    [market] => calls_nc_sell_daily
    [name] => partners
    [partners_id_fk] => calls_nc_sell_daily
    [seller] => partners
)
```

Actual:

```
Array
(
    [buyer] => partners
    [market] => partners
    [name] => partners
    [partners_id_fk] => partners
    [seller] => partners
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mysql_field_table()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_field_table) according to the PHP documentation takes the fields *offset*  and not its name as a second parameter. So your name will get converted to a number, which results in a zero for all iterations.

```
$tables = array();
for($i=0;$i<$elements;$i++) {
   $name =  mysql_field_name($result,$i);
   $tables[$name] = mysql_field_table($result, $i);
}
print_r($tables);
```

> string mysql_field_table ( resource $result , int $field_offset )
>
> **field_offset**
>
> The numerical field offset. The field_offset starts at 0. If field_offset does not exist, an error of level E_WARNING is also issued.